# Is the cone over Grassmannian manifold $Gr_2(\mathbb{C}^n)$ an open set of a determinantal variety?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, determinant, projective-geometry, affine-geometry, grassmannian

Let $Gr_2(\mathbb{C}^n)$ the Grassmann manifold of the planes in $\mathbb{C}^n$. It is, via Plucker embedding, a projective variety. If we consider the cone $C$ over $Gr_2(\mathbb{C}^n)$, is it possible to prove that $C$ is an open set of a determinantal variety? If yes, how can I prove it? Thank you!

Comment: I don't think so. If you take the simplest nontrivial Grassmannian, namely $Gr(2,4)$, its equation in $\mathbb P^5$ is $x_0x_1-x_2x_4+x_3x_5$ - of degree $2$. But every determinant of degree $2$ is binomial.

Comment: In this situation the cone is an open set of a determinantal variety because the Plucker relations give us an antisimmetric $2 \times 4$ matrix (say $M$), and $Pf(M)$ is the square of a determinant...

Comment: Ah, I hadn't thought of that! Thank you, that made the question a lot more interesting.

Comment: I am interested to know why the cone over $Gr(k,n)$ is not a determinantal variety if $k$ is strictly bigger then 2.